# Can I download app.R script and data of my shiny app from the shiny website?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps

I have a `shiny` app deployed on [www.shinyapps.io](https://www.shinyapps.io/). The app includes a data set and one script (`app.R`).

All of a sudden I lost all the access to the data and the script on my local machine. Is there a way that I can download the script `app.R` and the data from [www.shinyapps.io](https://www.shinyapps.io/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you login to shinyapps and click on the app name in the dashboard, you should see "Bundle - Download" in the Overview. This will download a tar file which you can uncompress. It should contain `app.R` plus the other files required to make the app run at shinyapps.