# how to download app.R from my own shiny web app

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

So my problem is I lost my Shiny file but already upload it to Shiny, I want to restore my file and download the app.R and www folder from my own Shiny web app.
I tried to download it from `bundle` from shinyapp.io

[image]

I follow the instruction from this q&a [Can I download app.R script and data of my shiny app from the shiny website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69863001/can-i-download-app-r-script-and-data-of-my-shiny-app-from-the-shiny-website) and I get tar.gz but when I extract it / open the file it doesn't contain my app.R nor my www folder instead it gave me this:

[image]

Comment: It works for me. You have to perform two decompressings. First decompress the `tar.gz`. This will give a `tar` file. Then decompress this `tar` file, this will give a folder containing your app. I'm using 7-Zip to decompress.